# How can i center and horizontal this <p>

Tags: html, css

I need to center the a paragraf in the CSS. I also want the text to appear horizontial.

```
<section class="test">
        <div class="test1">
            <p class="result1"> SUCCESS </p11>
            <p class="testnumber1"> TEST# </p12> 
            <p class="date1"> DATE </p13> 
        </div>
</section>
```

Here is the CSS

```
p.result1, p.result2 , p.result3, p.result4{
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:900;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried google?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18200485/1592884

Answer (score 2):

To center text horizontally apply:

```
text-align: center;
```

to the paragraphs that you want to center.

If you want to center the div you just need to provide it a width and set the left and right margins to auto:

```
width: 20%;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: Thanks, it is fixed now!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center the text, you can use the 'text-align'.

```
p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r7gpcy5z/)

[More info](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-align/)

Try some research by yourself. There is a lot of resource about html and css online.